How can I make the design of the dropdown button menu and the selected element different on flutter?
I'm new to flutter. I have a dropdown button. İts design like this.

I want the horizontal version of this design to be displayed when I click the button.Like This;
And I want it to switch back to the vertical design after selecting an item.Like this;

Here is my codes;
DropdownButton<int?>(
                    value: controller.selectedCategoryNu.value,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                    underline: const SizedBox(
                      height: 0,
                      width: 0,
                    ),
                    hint: Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: Text(
                        category.name,
                        style:
                            const TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16),
                      ),
                    ),
                    iconSize: 25,
                    alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                    dropdownColor: Colors.white,
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black, //<-- SEE HERE
                    ),
                    icon: const Icon(
                      Icons.arrow_drop_down,

                      color: Colors.black, // <-- SEE HERE
                    ),
                    onChanged: (int? newValue) {
                    
                    },
                    items: () {
                      List<DropdownMenuItem<int?>> items = controller
                          .subCategories(category.nu)
                          .map<DropdownMenuItem<int?>>((CategoryModel value) {
                        return DropdownMenuItem<int?>(
                          value: value.nu,
                          child: Text(
                            value.adi,
                          ),
                        );
                      }).toList();
                      items.insert(
                          0,
                          DropdownMenuItem<int?>(
                              value: category.nu,
                              child: Text(
                                category.name,
                              )));
                      return items;
                    }())

I've tried many approaches, but I couldn't get the listed and selected items to look different.
